# Optional named key in object

Tags: flowtype

I have an array of objects. The objects must have LabelKey key, and an optional IdKey. For example:

```
const items: ListItem = [
  { name:'Apple', fruit:'apple' },
  { name:'Orange', fruit:'orange' }
];

alert({
  items,
  labelKey: 'name', // defaults to "label"
  idKey: 'fruit', // defaults to "id"
});
```

I am trying to define a type for `ListItem`.

It is optional to have key by `IdKey`.

I tried this:

```
type LabelKey = string | 'label'
type IdKey = 'id' | string
type ListItem = {
   [LabelKey]: string,
   [IdKey]?: any
}
```

However it is treating them like "indexers". And the question mark on IdKey is a syntax error apprently.

Comment: Indexer properties specify that any key in the object has some value type T. If that key exists, it's associated with the value T. If it doesn't exist, well, it doesn't exist. So they're already sorta optional. That's the reason the "?:" optional syntax doesn't work: it would be redundant.

Comment: Darn, thanks James again!

Answer (score 2):

From your description and example I guess you want to define type which is object with two dynamic properties one of which is optional, so these two object should be the same type:

```
var v1: YourType = {
    anything: 'anything',
    another: 'another'
};

var v2: YourType = {
    different: 'anything'
}
```

If so I don't think that is achievable with flowtype. Objects property names are part of the type. It can't be anytthing other than string anyway.

There is no way to define object that you can use in the way like:

```
function doStuff(items, labelKey, idKey) {
    for (i in items) {
        var key = items[i][labelKey]
        var id  = items[i][idKey]
    }
}
```

In this case the only way is to use `Array<Object>` type

---

What you can do is to define types of specific properties. From your example, it could be

```
type Fruit = {
    name: string,
    fruit: ?string // not "fruit?: string"
}

type FruitsList = Array<Fruit>

const items: FruitsList = [
  { name:'Apple', fruit:'apple' },
  { name:'Orange', fruit:'orange' }
];
```

If you want to deal with objects with different/mixed properties, you can use Union types.

Two examples:

First: **Different array types**, more strict

```
type Fruit = {
  name: string,
  fruit: ?string
};

type FruitsList = Array<Fruit>;

type Vegetable = {
  name: string,
  vegetable: ?string
};

type VegetablesList = Array<Vegetable>;

type ArrayOfFruitsOrArrayOfVegetables = FruitsList | VegetablesList;

let items1: FruitsList = [
  { name:'Apple', fruit:'apple' },
  { name:'Orange', fruit: undefined }
];

// OR

var items2: VegetablesList = [
  { name:'Cucumber', vegetable:'cucumber' },
  { name:'Potato', vegetable: undefined }
];

function testFirst(items: ArrayOfFruitsOrArrayOfVegetables) {
 return items;
}

testFirst(items1);
testFirst(items2);
```

[Check it out in sandbox](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AMQE4CuAliqALygDeiooAdgIYC2WAXKAM4r7H0DmAGlqhIRUhwD83XgMQBfANzJ02POJScAMsW4VQAQXz5GaADwESKAHzLUmHADUs-LCkYAjaDko06TVg4ZPiERADcXN09vKWC5JRUHUGdXdy8sbV0ySiMTcxSo9NtEtVzTAHlIS1JOcvwytEqCtO9OfWrNHT0AH2TIloyulDtvMlIsZk4ARg4OzL1KAG0RKgYWdgByAwwMbw3BUQ02DcYdvdB5YTpVgM26xgEsfcOrDkJ6ABMsSD4sD4vEABdOwgUDlABKyDCjHwoHGkwATBxmtFBll9MtrmtAhsAMKEADGhGYHiw+GeEVSqOORKJJLJGwuV2o2M2AAVYO4ULAKf1qaB3l8fvQ-gDgchIO8CShiLB6KAUBkULhiPhuAAKeGcDgNSpzOq6yAo9KcACU1Fo+DchHw8q1ynkKiVKrVKE1ismU1NykV3BdGq1CO9QA)

Second. **Array of objects with different types**, less strict

```
type Fruit = {
  name: string,
  fruit: ?string
}

type Vegetable = {
  name: string,
  vegetable: ?string
}

type Grocery = Fruit | Vegetable

type ArrayOfGroceries = Array<Grocery>

// so usage is

var items: ArrayOfGroceries = [
    { name:'Apple', fruit:'apple' },
    { name:'Orange', fruit: undefined },
    { name:'Cucumber', vegetable:'cucumber' },
    { name:'Potato', vegetable:undefined }
];

function testSecond(items: ArrayOfGroceries) {
  return items
}

testSecond(items)
```

([sandbox](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AMQE4CuAliqALygDeiooAdgIYC2WAXKAM4r7H0DmAGlqhIRUhwD83XgMQBfZOmygAaln5YUjAEbQclGnSasOMvkJEA3DVt36p5uYtSYcAcXywAxlnxoKPHEyAB81W209LCU3UABBfHxGNAB5SE8fP2IsTkCEpLQAHgzffwA+ZBAuWFBCTkZNUGJOZCtGfCaULGZODnzktJKsnMCAbRE6KgYWdgByOIwMfVnBUWC2WcZF5dB5YTpJ6dNZlKSBLBW1khQOQnoAEyxIPix73f2DqZM5gGFCb0IzB0fkuNk0kQcswBAKBIPeE2oRzmAAVYNoULBQRF7Ow7o9nvRXrtEABdADcyEgd28KGIsHooC63AAylhvPT7gAKUjdXrxRIDdJeUrZTgASmoInwWkI+AZPJ6CiUORQrPZD25XR6YqAA))

---

Some docs:

[Maybe Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/)

[Object Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/)

[Array Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/)

Comment: Thank you Nikita. I have upvoted. I don't understand this quite yet. I will understand then accept. Thanks very much!